# Value Error: Math Domain Error! I want to get the values of angles from sine equation

Tags: python, angle

#How could I fix this problem? Your support will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
liquid_data='component.csv'
df1=pd.read_csv(liquid_data)
df1
YSP=1
YSN=0.62
YSLW=42.94
Ys=YSLW+2*(YSP*YSN)**0.5
print(Ys)
df1.YL
N=len(df1.YL)
```

print(N)

```
import numpy as np
YSL=np.zeros(N)
YL=np.zeros(N)
YLLW=np.zeros(N)
YLN=np.zeros(N)
YLP=np.zeros(N)
for i in range(0,N):
YSL[i]=Ys+df1.YL[i]-2*((YSLW*df1.YLLW[i])**0.5+(YSP*df1.YLN[i])**0.5+(YSN*df1.YLP[i])**0.5)
print(YSL)

import cmath
Radian=np.zeros(N)
Theta=np.zeros(N)
Ys=44.51
YL=np.zeros(N)
YSL=np.zeros(N)

import math
for i in range (N):
        Radian[i]=math.asin((Ys-YSL[i])/YL[i])
        print(Radian)
```

```
#liquid_data
    Liquid  YLLW    YLP YLN YL
0   1   28.85   0.00    2.7 28.85
1   2   50.80   0.00    0.0 50.80
2   3   25.35   0.00    0.0 25.35
3   4   18.80   0.02    68.0    22.40
4   5   25.20   0.00    13.1    25.20
5   6   29.00   1.90    47.0    48.00
6   7   39.00   2.28    39.6    58.00
7   8   34.00   3.92    57.4    64.00
8   9   20.14   0.00    0.0 20.14
9   10  18.20   0.06    77.0    22.50
10  11  27.50   0.00    18.0    27.50
11  12  21.80   25.50   25.5    72.80
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Please tag. Also, look up what causes a domain error in `asin`.

Comment: It is Python programming language and run in jupyter notebook. It said that there are some negative values for which this error is occurring. But, I want to know how to fix this problem. Thank you.

Comment: `arcsin` is only defined for values between -1 and +1.  Have you printed all the values of `(Ys-YSL[i])/YL[i]` to make sure they fall into that range?

Comment: Actually, I know this has caused the error behind that code. But, unfortunately, I couldn't fix that problem what I have to do to bring the values whose are in this range. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do if the values are out of range?

Comment: I just want to get the angle values in radian. That's it. Every coding seems fine for me, just failed to get the angle values. If you could show me what is the solution to remove this problem, then it will be very helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. There are no angle values for domain errors! It's like asking for the square root of a negative number. "Just tell me the square root of -1, is that so hard?" (Okay, so there is an angle value if you use complex numbers. So `numpy.arcsin((Ys-YSL[i])/YL[i]+0j)`. Good luck with that.)